# undefined index arrays cannot refer to my other php page?

Tags: php, arrays

```
<?php
define("TITLE", "Menu Item | Risque");

include('includes/header.php');

$menuItem = '';
$dish = '';

if (isset($_GET['item'])) {

    $menuItem = $_GET['item']; 

    $dish = $menuItems[$menuItem];
}

function suggestedTip ($price, $tip){

    $totalTip = $price * $tip;
}
?>

<center><img src = "hr.png">
<br>

<div id = "dish">


    <h1><?php $dish = array(); echo $dish["title"]; ?> <span class="price"><sup>$</sup><?php echo $dish["price"]; ?></span></h1>
    <p><?php echo $dish["blurb"]; ?></p>
    <br>
    <p><strong>Suggested beverage: <?php echo $dish["drink"]; ?></strong></p>
    <p><em>Suggested tip: <sup>$</sup><?php suggestedTip($dish["price"], 0.20); ?></em></p>

</div>
```

arrays.php codes are below
somehow the values inside the array does not show up in my page

```
<?php

$navItems = array (

                array(
                    'slug'  => "index.php",
                    'title' => "Home"
                     ),

                array(
                    'slug'  => "menu.php",
                    'title' => "Menu"
                     ),

                array(
                    'slug'  => "contact.php",
                    'title' => "Contact"
                     ),

                );



$menuItems = array(

                "club-sandwich" => array(

                    "name"  => "Club Sandwich",
                    "price" => 11,
                    "blurb" => "Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet fatback landjaeger ullamco pariatur. Nostrud laboris et, duis drumstick eiusmod kevin ut aliquip. Filet mignon short ribs tenderloin short loin kielbasa non pork chop aliqua. Jerky shank tri-tip capicola, non andouille tenderloin cupidatat turducken meatball pork beef eu shoulder jowl.",
                    "drink" => "Club Soda"

                ),

                "dill-salmon" => array(

                    "name"  => "Lemon &amp; Dill Salmon",
                    "price" => 18,
                    "blurb" => "Pork belly tempor ground round qui exercitation, jowl leberkas sed voluptate excepteur jerky. Reprehenderit veniam cow, quis in ribeye andouille eu pastrami eiusmod exercitation dolor.",
                    "drink" => "Fancy Wine"

                ),

                "super-salad" => array(

                    "name"  => "The Super Salad<sup>&reg;</sup>",
                    "price" => 34,
                    "blurb" => "Gumbo beet greens corn soko endive gumbo gourd. Parsley shallot courgette tatsoi pea sprouts fava bean collard greens dandelion okra wakame tomato. Dandelion cucumber earthnut pea peanut soko zucchini.",
                    "drink" => "Jug o' Water"

                ),

                "mexican-barbacoa" => array(

                    "name"  => "Mexican Barbacoa",
                    "price" => 23,
                    "blurb" => "I love fruitcake danish caramels. Tart danish pastry liquorice chocolate cake fruitcake. Bear claw gingerbread muffin I love apple pie apple pie tiramisu brownie chocolate. Sweet roll cotton candy cupcake gingerbread gummies jelly-o. Muffin I love croissant I love jelly-o brownie jelly beans. Toffee I love pastry.",
                    "drink" => "Beer with a lime"

                ),

             );
```

?>

I am new to PHP but I have a project that is due soon but I keep getting undefined error for `title`, `price` and `blurb`.

I would appreciate it if anyone can help.

Comment: where you filled $dish["title"]?

Comment: shall i show you the whole codes?

Comment: You just create an empty array and call for some index of that array without import some value on it...

Comment: The main point is here `<?php $dish = array(); echo $dish["title"]; ?>`, _You just create an empty array and call for some index of that array without import some value on it..._.

Comment: Where is your **another php page**?

Comment: how do i solve the duplicate problem?

Comment: oh i see you meant the array was empty sorry i misinterpreted just now. how do i import the codes then?

Comment: what you are getting in `$_GET['item']` ?? use `print_r($_GET['item'])` to print and show the output..

Comment: foreach ($navItems as $item) {
  
   echo "<li><a href =\"$item[slug]\">$item[title]</a></li>";
  
  }

Comment: the codes above were from my other php page nav.php if this info helps

Comment: i have tried print_r and it did not work

Comment: it just for testing include your array.php page and try

Comment: sorry i am confused how do i include that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have declared empty array for the variable **$dish**. So there is no way to get indexes like **title, price, blurb** from the **empty array**. If you are trying to get values from database, then store the db result in the variable $dish and proceed. Also always check if the array index exist before you echo it using **isset()** function. Else it will throw notice error in error maximum mode and in error log file. Refer the code below.

```
<h1><?php if(isset($dish["title"])) echo $dish["title"]; ?> <span class="price"><sup>$</sup><?php if(isset($dish["price"])) echo $dish["price"]; ?></span></h1>
<p><?php echo if(isset($dish["blurb"])) $dish["blurb"]; ?></p>
<br>
<p><strong>Suggested beverage: <?php if(isset($dish["drink"])) echo $dish["drink"]; ?></strong></p>
<p><em>Suggested tip: <sup>$</sup><?php if(isset($dish["price"])) suggestedTip($dish["price"], 0.20); ?></em></p>
```

So this code will not display the error.

Comment: oh i am not using mysql

Comment: i just completed the isset and there is no error now, however my page is blank and does not show the relative information from arrays.php

Comment: Yes because your array is empty. If you are not using database, then assign some value to the variable. Tell me, why do you want to process the empty array?

Comment: hmm it is empty? i thought it isnt because all my datas are in the arrays.php as shown in my question

Comment: perhaprs i connect the arrays wrongly

Comment: oh i did connect wrongly i found my error its working fine now! thank you so much for your help!! it was invaluable to me!!

Comment: Great!! Please upvote if my post is useful to you.

Comment: hmm think i am unable to upvote you because i do not have enough rep points. sorry about that!